# Imprimir valor del atributo solo si se le ha dado click en plantilla html

Tags: javascript

me ha surgido un problema, tengo una plantilla html que imprimo con valores de un array, en esa plantilla tengo un boton y cuando le dé click debe imprimirme el valor que tiene en el atributo name, el problema es que no se como hacer que me imprima el valor solo del boton que estoy clicando, me imprime pero solo del primer boton, trate de hacer una funcion imprimir y el metodo onclick() peor ni asi funciono, espero puedan ayudarme, se los agradezco muchisimo de antemano.

**Mi función**

```
var hillo = $("#hillo").click(function(){

    var  arreglo = extraerJSON(datos);
    var filtrado = filtrarCedis(arreglo,'HERMOSILLO');

    $.each(filtrado, function(i,item){
        var tr = `<tr>
        <td>`+filtrado[i][1]+`</td>
        <td>`+filtrado[i][3]+`</td>
        <td>`+filtrado[i][2]+`</td>
        <td>`+filtrado[i][4]+`</td>
        <td>`+filtrado[i][5]+`</td>
        <td> <a class='btn btn-success' href='#' name= ${filtrado[i][4]} onclick='${imprimir(filtrado[i][4])}'>Ver</a></td>
        </tr>`;

        $("#example").append(tr);
    });
});
```

//función imprimir

```
function imprimir(serie){
    console.log(serie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pasa como parámetro a la función el método `this` a `imprimir()` después en la función imprimir accede al name con `e.name`.

```js
var hillo = $("#hillo").click(function(){

    var  arreglo = extraerJSON(datos);
    var filtrado = filtrarCedis(arreglo,'HERMOSILLO');

    $.each(filtrado, function(i,item){
        var tr = `<tr>
        <td>`+filtrado[i][1]+`</td>
        <td>`+filtrado[i][3]+`</td>
        <td>`+filtrado[i][2]+`</td>
        <td>`+filtrado[i][4]+`</td>
        <td>`+filtrado[i][5]+`</td>
        <td> <a class='btn btn-success' href='#' name= ${filtrado[i][4]} onclick='${imprimir(this)}'>Ver</a></td>
        </tr>`;

        $("#example").append(tr);
    });
});
//función imprimir

function imprimir(e){
    console.log(e.name);
}
```

Comment: Gracias hermano, pero no funcionó :(